# Facebook C# ASP.NET SDK simulate Pandora experience?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

You'll notice if you are logged into Facebook and browse to Pandora.com to listen to music, if you are not logged into your Pandora account it will detect that you are logged into Facebook, find the music you like, and start playing it.

I never granted access to Pandora or anything like that, how exactly are they doing this?  Is this possible with the new http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com ?  I am using the new version 5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instant authentication is not possible. That is something that Facebook has done for a limited number of companies. Your app will have to go through the normal authentication/authorization process.